# How to pipe results of a foreach loop to an output file?

Tags: powershell, pipe, output, pipeline

I have the following code that gets usernames from a list and then retrieves their emails.
I'd like to have this outputted to eventually send automatic emails to these specific addresses.

With the code below, only the last object in the text file is recorded in the outfile.

```
$users = (get-content c:\temp\Fredro.txt)
foreach ($EUT in $users) {
Get-ADUser -Identity $EUT | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Out-File -filepath C:\temp\exomailinglist.txt}
```

How to pipe results of a foreach loop to an output file?

Comment: Try adding `-Append`  to `Out-File`. Doesn't look like any faulty logic, so give that a shot. You can also get rid of the *grouping operator* surrounding `(Get-Content ...)`, unless you're trying to force it to be an array, which you should use the *array subexpression operator* `@(..)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the file on every pass through your foreach loop if an ADUser is found.  As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) mentioned in comments if you were to add `-Append` to the `Out-File` cmdlet this would solve your problem of the file only containing the last item.  I would also recommend adding `-ExpandProperty` to `Select-Object` to avoid having the header "UserPrincipalName" also added to the file each time.

```
$users = (Get-Content c:\temp\Fredro.txt)
foreach ($EUT in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $EUT | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName | 
            Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\exomailinglist.txt -Append
}
```

Rather than writing to the file in the foreach loop for each user though I would instead recommend to capture all ADUsers first and then write all of the items at once to the file, possibly like this:

```
$users = (Get-Content c:\temp\Fredro.txt)
$adUsers = foreach ($EUT in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $EUT | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName 
}
$adUsers | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\exomailinglist.txt
```

And lastly, the best option in my opinion, combine it all into one pipeline which would look like this.

```
Get-Content c:\temp\Fredro.txt | 
    Get-ADUser | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName | 
            Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\exomailinglist.txt
```

This method would avoid the foreach loop completely.  `Get-ADUser` accepts Identity from the pipeline *byvalue* so we can just pipe each line from `Get-Content` directly.  `Out-File` will wait on all items from the pipeline before writing to the file.